# How to create a global function for a PostgreSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I have a use case where I want to create a function which i can use on every database available on my PostgreSQL instance so I can give execute grant to a non-super user.

Task of this function would be to get the user password hash from pg_shadow.

I will add this user to Pg bouncer user list to access user match user hashes and give them access to the PostgreSQL instance.

I don't have much experience working with databases. So it would be great help

I would also appreciate an alternative approach

`Function` I want to use in every database

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_search(uname TEXT) RETURNS TABLE (usename name, passwd text) as
$$
  WITH myuser as (SELECT $1 as fullusername) SELECT fullusername as usename, passwd FROM pg_catalog.pg_shadow INNER JOIN myuser ON usename = substring(fullusername from '[^@]*')
$$
LANGUAGE sql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

```sql
CREATE ROLE pgbuser WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'pgbouncer';
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION user_search(text) TO pgbuser;
```

Comment: User created functions are per database. The closest you could come is to create the function in the `template1` database and then new databases will get it when they are created per rules here [Template databases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html). For existing databases you would have to add it to each.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Would it be possible for a superuser to create a function in the [`pg_catalog` schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-CATALOG)?

Comment: Create this function into the template1 database. Every new database created, by default using this template, will have your function.

Comment: @Bergi. Tampering with the system catalogs is not a good idea. For one thing they will not survive a dump/restore or a pg_upgrade(I believe, not confirmed).